# Why do C# struct instance methods calling instance methods on a struct field first check ecx?

Tags: c#, x86, jit

Why does the X86 for the following C# method `CallViaStruct` include the `cmp` instruction?

```cs
struct Struct {
    public void NoOp() { }
}
struct StructDisptach {

    Struct m_struct;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void CallViaStruct() {
        m_struct.NoOp();
        //push        ebp  
        //mov         ebp,esp  
        //cmp         byte ptr [ecx],al  
        //pop         ebp  
        //ret
    }
}
```

Here is a more complete program that can be compiled with various (release) decompilations as comments. I expected the X86 for `CallViaStruct` in both `ClassDispatch` and `StructDispatch` types to be the same however the version in `StructDispatch` (extracted above) includes a `cmp` instruction while the other does not.

It appears the `cmp` instruction is an idiom is used to ensure a variable is not null; dereferencing a register with value 0 triggers an `av` that is turned into a `NullReferenceException`. However in `StructDisptach.CallViaStruct` I cannot conceive of a way for `ecx` to be null given it's pointing at a struct.

UPDATE: The answer I'm looking to accept will include code that causes a NRE to be thrown by `StructDisptach.CallViaStruct` by having it's `cmp` instruction dereference a zeroed `ecx` register. Note this is easy to do with either of the `CallViaClass` methods by setting `m_class = null` and impossible to do with `ClassDisptach.CallViaStruct` as there is no `cmp` instruction.

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace NativeImageTest {

    struct Struct {
        public void NoOp() { }
    }

    class Class {
        public void NoOp() { }
    }

    class ClassDisptach {

        Class m_class;
        Struct m_struct;

        internal ClassDisptach(Class cls) {
            m_class = cls;
            m_struct = new Struct();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public void CallViaClass() {
            m_class.NoOp();
            //push        ebp  
            //mov         ebp,esp  
            //mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx+4]  
            //cmp         byte ptr [eax],al  
            //pop         ebp  
            //ret  
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public void CallViaStruct() {
            m_struct.NoOp();
            //push        ebp
            //mov         ebp,esp
            //pop         ebp
            //ret
        }
    }

    struct StructDisptach {

        Class m_class;
        Struct m_struct;

        internal StructDisptach(Class cls) {
            m_class = cls;
            m_struct = new Struct();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public void CallViaClass() {
            m_class.NoOp();
            //push        ebp  
            //mov         ebp,esp  
            //mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx]  
            //cmp         byte ptr [eax],al  
            //pop         ebp  
            //ret  
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public void CallViaStruct() {
            m_struct.NoOp();
            //push        ebp  
            //mov         ebp,esp  
            //cmp         byte ptr [ecx],al  
            //pop         ebp  
            //ret  
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var classDispatch = new ClassDisptach(new Class());
            classDispatch.CallViaClass();
            classDispatch.CallViaStruct();

            var structDispatch = new StructDisptach(new Class());
            structDispatch.CallViaClass();
            structDispatch.CallViaStruct();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Turns out it's possible to use `callvirt` on a non-virtual function which has a side effect of null checking the this pointer. While this is the case for the `CallViaClass` callsite (which is why we see the null check there) `StructDispatch.CallViaStruct` uses a `call` instruction.

```
.method public hidebysig instance void  CallViaClass() cil managed noinlining
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldfld      class NativeImageTest.Class NativeImageTest.StructDisptach::m_class
  IL_0006:  callvirt   instance void NativeImageTest.Class::NoOp()
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method StructDisptach::CallViaClass

.method public hidebysig instance void  CallViaStruct() cil managed noinlining
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldflda     valuetype NativeImageTest.Struct NativeImageTest.StructDisptach::m_struct
  IL_0006:  call       instance void NativeImageTest.Struct::NoOp()
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method StructDisptach::CallViaStruct
```

UPDATE: There was a suggestion that the `cmp` could be trapping for the case where a `null` this pointer was not trapped for at the call site. If that were the case then I'd expect the the `cmp` to occur once at the top of the method. However it appears once for each call to `NoOp`:

```
struct StructDisptach {

    Struct m_struct;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void CallViaStruct() {
        m_struct.NoOp();
        m_struct.NoOp();
        //push        ebp  
        //mov         ebp,esp  
        //cmp         byte ptr [ecx],al  
        //cmp         byte ptr [ecx],al  
        //pop         ebp  
        //ret  
    }
}
```

Comment: Triggering a NRE on that `cmp` is easy if you remove the `Class` field from `StructDisptach` and then call `unsafe { ((StructDisptach*)0)->CallViaStruct(); }`, but I guess using an unsafe context is cheating ;)

Comment: HaHA! Great idea! However it kinda seems doubtful the JIT would go through the trouble to trap for that case -- especially given the class field. And even if that's the reason (and were seeing an unoptimized case) if I place two calls to `NoOp` I get the check twice. So then the question would be what's the second one for?

Comment: Yes, that's why I say it'd be cheating - if I knew the answer you bet I'd tell you :) It *may* just be an oversight in the JIT for all I know, since I can't think of any better explanation for that `cmp` being here :-\

Comment: Are your disassembled samples from a debug build? It might be the compiler/JITer way of leaving at least one instruction that can be said to "belong" to your no-op function so that you can step through the source line by line.

Comment: Turns out the instruction is there because of the `ldflda` and not the `call`. Using ildasm/ilasm to rewrite the method shows this to be the case. So seems in my case it could be optimized away. However, in the non trivial case, the next question is does `ldfda` need the `cmp` instruction when the field is in a struct?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:  The JITter cannot prove that the struct is not referenced by a pointer, and must at least dereference at least once on every call to NoOp() for correct behavior.

---

Long answer:  Structs are weird.

The JITter is conservative.  Wherever possible, it can only optimize the code in ways that it can be *absolutely* certain produce correct behavior.  "Mostly-correct" isn't good enough.

So now here's an example scenario that would break if the JITter optimized away the dereference.  Consider the following facts:

First:  Remember that structs can (and do!) exist outside C# — a pointer to a StructDispatch could come from unmanaged code, for example.  As Lucas pointed out, you can use pointers to cheat; but the JITter can't know for sure that you aren't using pointers to StructDispatch somewhere else in the code.

Second:  Remember that in unmanaged code, which is the biggest reason structs exist in the first place, all bets are off.  Just because you just read a value from memory doesn't mean it'll be the same value or even *be* a value the next time you read that same exact address.  Threading, and multiprocessing, can literally have something change that value on the next clock tick, to say nothing of non-CPU actors like DMA.  A parallel thread could VirtualFree() the page that contains that struct, and the JITter has to guard against that.  You asked for reads from memory, so you get reads from memory.  My guess is that if you kicked in the optimizer, it would remove one of those cmp instructions, but I highly doubt that it would remove both.

Third:  Exceptions are real code too.  NullReferenceException doesn't necessarily stop the program; it can be caught and handled.  That means that from the JITter's perspective, NRE is more like an if-statement than a goto:  It's a kind of condition branch that must be handled and considered on every memory dereference.

So now put those pieces together.

The JITter doesn't know — and can't know — that you're not using unsafe C# or an external source somewhere else to interact with StructDispatch's memory.  It doesn't produce separate implementations of CallViaStruct(), one for "probably safe C# code" and one for "possibly risky external code;" it produces the conservative version for possibly risky scenarios, always.  This means that it can't just cut out calls to NoOp() in full, because there's no guarantee that StructDispatch isn't, say, mapped to an address that isn't even paged into memory.

It knows that NoOp() is empty and can be elided (the call can go away), but it at least has to *simulate* the ldfla by poking the memory address of the struct, because there could be code depending on that NRE being raised.  Memory dereferences are like if-statements:  They can cause a branch, and failing to cause a branch may result in a broken program.  Microsoft can't make assumptions and just say, "Your code shouldn't rely on that."  Imagine the angry phone call to Microsoft if an NRE wasn't written to a business's error log just because the JITter decided it wasn't an "important enough" NRE to trigger in the first place.  The JITter has no choice but to dereference that address at least once to ensure correct semantics.

---

Classes don't have any of these concerns; there's no enforced memory weirdness with a class.  But structs, though, are quirkier.

Comment: On your last paragraph, regarding what the compiler may or may not assume, it depends on whether accessing a struct via a null pointer is defined or not. If it is _undefined behaviour_, compiler writers can (and frequently) not just ignore what one would usually consider "sanity checks" but may also even *remove* the ones you put there explicitly because the compiler is allowed to assume that UB cannot occur. See, for example, [this lovely fellow](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30475) complaining about a check on signed overflow (UB in C) being removed by GCC.

Comment: It's a valid point for languages like C that have undefined behavior as a part of their spec.  But C# isn't supposed to have undefined behavior (within the limits of being able to define semantics for a typical programming language).  That forces this kind of issue:  Once you must define behavior for all operations, you don't get to ignore any of those behaviors when they're inconvenient or might result in slower code.  C# must dereference that memory because the NRE is expected, well-defined behavior for accessing memory through a null pointer, and removing the NRE would violate the spec.

Comment: Without checking the spec I couldn't know, but structs are supposed to be always non-null when not boxed, so a non-virtual function of a struct should not *need* to check its "this". In fact, even if you were using unsafe code to make `MyStruct* p = null;` and then tried to return `*p` as a variable of type `MyStruct`, the NRE should occur at `*p`, not later. The same applies for unboxing; trying to convert a null Object to a variable `MyStruct s` should raise the NRE then, not later when calling members of `s`.

Comment: You're still making the assumption that managed-code boxing rules always apply. If I declare an unsafe method that takes in a pointer to a struct, and combine a call to that method with a pointer that comes from a call to an unmanaged C function, there are no guarantees of any kind on that pointer. It could be on the managed heap. It could be on an unmanaged heap. It could be C NULL. It could point to memory-mapped I/O. It could be anything, and the JITter *must* conservatively guard against those possibilities.

Comment: yes, but you are still talking about _pointers_. My point is precisely that the problems you are mention are, by design, confined to _unsafe code_. You cannot get a NRE accessing a variable of type `MyStruct`, it is impossible by the very design of the CLR. At most you could have your function taking a `MyStruct*` _or_ a boxed object, and that pointer/object _could_ be `null`, but what I'm saying is that per the CLR enforcement you would get the NRE when trying to dereference it and assign it to a struct variable, _not later when accessing the non-pointer struct variable_.

Comment: C# `null` isn't the only thing that can trigger an NRE: A missing memory page or memory-mapped I/O can do the same, and the validity of those addresses can change after you test them. That means that when you invoke `structDispatch->CallViaStruct()`, that call may be valid on `StructDispatch`'s memory, but if something like VirtualFree() is done to that same memory by another thread or if I/O moves the pages around before `m_struct.NoOp()`, then `m_struct.NoOp();` must fail, and the only way to ensure that semantic is to probe memory. The CLR is a leaky abstraction, and the JITter knows that.

Comment: Do the situations you describe cause a NRE? I don't think so, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) states that the `call` instruction is not among those that can trigger a NRE (`callvirt` is, however). I'm not saying that the _JIT_ cannot place the check due to its own reasons, like the ones you describe, in order to take some other action (like remapping memory, synchronising some map with the GC or simply crashing orderly), so you may be right about the memory poke being necessary, but it's not a _CLR_-mandated behaviour.

Comment: The same page you linked also states that `ldflda` can generate an NRE, just as you'd expect it would. Even when the JIT elides the rest of the call logic, it can't elide the NRE that could come from the `ldflda`, which is exactly the behavior that Christopher King is seeing. Remember that NRE isn't handled by an explicit check against a "null" value; it's handled by trying to just *use* the value, and if the CPU raises an interrupt trying to access a missing/protected page, you get an NRE, regardless of *why* the interrupt was really raised.

Comment: Okay, so since in OP's code that struct method has no way to know if its `this` is safe, it needs to perform the check, even if only to generate the side effect of a NRE if it is null or somehow invalid, right? If this was a static method with a struct _local variable_ instead, there would be no way that a NRE would be raised because the struct would always be valid - in that case what I said about the NRE being raised earlier would apply, but not in OP's code.

Comment: Correct. The struct method can't be sure `this` is a safe value, so it probes memory to let the CPU interrupt trigger, if necessary, to generate the NRE. I just tested the static version you described, and the entire call chain is elided as expected because the JITter can prove that the calls do nothing.